# Fresh Arch Install, no install issues, freezes at random points on the initial boot

Tags: arch-linux

I just finished installing Arch on my laptop to a second hard drive, had no issues at all during the install, but when I went to actually reboot into Arch it freezes at different points.  The first time it froze at Starting Bluetooth, the next time it froze at Kernel Device Manager and the third time it froze at asus backlight modules.  I've left it sitting there for over an hour and still got nothing from it.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?  I've got no clue where to even begin diagnosing this problem because of the fact it freezes at random places.

The laptop in question is an ASUS G75VW with Arch on the HDD formatted as GPT with the correct EFI partitions, etc.

Comment: I experienced the same kind of problem that you have but in RHEL. In the end it turned out the RAM had gone bad. May be you can check if the RAM has gone bad.

Comment: Arch Live boot media comes with memtest so you can run that to check your RAM. Also, if RAM is ok, I would suggest reinstalling, maybe you have missed something?

Comment: I did hear a scratching sound from the hard drive, but it was only for a second and I haven't heard it again and I've been listening out for it.  I've run hardware tests, memtest, my memory is all fine.  The hard drive tests came back good as well, guess there is a chance the drive is going back which would be causing the hangups, but I doubt it and was probably hearing something else.

Comment: To the poster above my last post, I've tested my memory/hdd and they came back all fine.  I've reinstalled Arch 4 times already making sure I did everything correctly, triple checked everything, so I'm at a lost.

Comment: @bryce to notify someone about a comment, include the person's name prefixed by a @. As I do here.

Comment: Thank you @FaheemMitha, did not know that.  Anyways, I'm going to do another install of Arch to see if I did in fact miss something, don't think I did, but never know.  Just weird how it's random where it freezes at though.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'nomodeset' as a boot parameter. This disables a modern UEFI graphics feature which most cards do not support circa 2014.
At the boot menu, press e to add the parameter.

Comment: KMS has nothing to do with UEFI, and most cards do support it in 2014...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a MacbookPro1,1. I use rEFInd, so I edited the boot parameters and added `nomodeset` to the end of the line. This solved the problem.